# JavaScript: Split and count words in string

Tags: javascript, string, function

For example I have input string with value "test test in string".

I need to do a function that will split every word and count each how many of them are in that string input.

The output should be like:
test: 2, in: 1, string: 1

Thanks a lot in advance for tip.

Comment: @Yousaf sure, I've splited that string input, but I don't know how to count frequency of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after splitting the string, you can use reduce function to count the frequency of each word

```js
const str = "test test in string";

const result = str.split(' ').reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : 1;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are cool with lodash, then:

```
_.countBy('test test in string'.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```js
var str = "test test test in string";
var res = str.split(" ");
  
var result = {};
  res.forEach(function(x) {
  result[x] = (result[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(result)
```